# Предупреждения при старте сервера lsfusion из под intellij idea

Tags: lsfusion

Подскажите что значат эти предупреждения в консоли

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by lsfusion.base.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Program%20Files/lsFusion%204/Server/server.jar) to method sun.util.locale.provider.HostLocaleProviderAdapterImpl.getDateFormatProvider()

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of lsfusion.base.ReflectionUtils

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Их можно не бояться, это не ошибки, а только warning'и, которые начали показываться начиная с 9-ой Java.

**UPD**: Начиная с версии 5.0-SNAPSHOT вывод этого предупреждения отключен.